# Models_committed not firing a function on model commit - FlaskSQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, signals, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get a signal - [models_committed](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/signals/) - to fire a function when my models are committed. Currently just does a standard print(), but I can't get the function to fire. Tried the decorator method and models_commited.connect(func, app) method.

**What I'm expecting to happen**
I commit some data to my database (into a model), then signal_thing() (located in **init**.py) prints 'hello - is this working' to the flask run console.

**What is actually happening**
Data is committed to the database (shows up in my web app) but nothing is printed to console, it seems signal_thing() does not fire.

I can't find much information about how to get Signals working properly on Flask?

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, models_committed, before_models_committed


def signal_thing(sender, changes, **kwargs):
    print('hello - is this working?')
    sender.print('hello - is this working')

models_committed.connect(signal_thing, app)
before_models_committed.connect(signal_thing, app)
```

**decorator method**

```
@models_commited.connect(app)
def signal_thing(sender, changes, **kwargs):
    print('hello - is this working?')
    sender.print('hello this worked')
```

**config**

SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS' is set to True.

```
<Config {'ENV': 'production', 'DEBUG': False, 'TESTING': False, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION': None, 'SECRET_KEY': 'shh', 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NA
ME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True,
 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200), 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'JSON_AS_ASCII': True, 'JSON_SORT_KEYS':
True, 'JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR': False, 'JSONIFY_MIMETYPE': 'application/json', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093, 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\\\ZigBot\\app.db', 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': True}>
```